# How do I embed a google docs form in my app through Android Studio?

Tags: java, forms, android-studio

I'm a beginner and I just wanted some advice on how to embed Google forms in my app and store that data in a spreadsheet. I've made a navigation drawer in my app and have set up an option called Registration. Whenever the user clicks on this, I want the google form for this registration to open inside my apo itself and once completed, that data to be stored in a Google spreadsheet. Can someone please guide me on how to do this?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the steps in this great tutorial to set up your form and results spreadsheet:
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/google-forms-collect-contact-info-mobile-device/

Where the tutorial says **“Go to live form” to open it again in your web browser,** instead you should add a web view in your app to display the form and submission button.

Comment: Could you please guide me on how to use webview?

Comment: Please see the Android tutorial here: https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Comment: You're welcome! If you could accept my answer, I would really appreciate it :)